# What is multi-scale architecture?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, normalizing-flow

When I was reading the paper ["Density Estimation using Real NVP"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.08803), I have found the term "multi scale architecture".

> We implement a multi-scale architecture using a squeezing operation:
> for each channel, it divides the image into subsquares of shape 2 × 2
> × c, then reshapes them into subsquares of shape 1 × 1 × 4c. The squeezing operation transforms an s × s × c tensor into an s
> 2 × s 2 × 4c tensor, effectively trading spatial size for number of channels.

But I don't understand, what is this multi scale architecture? Can anybody explain it or point me to a direction which explains it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CNNs are typically constructed by stacking convolutional layers on top of each other, with each convolutional layer taking in the previous feature map and producing a successive feature map. The spatial resolution of the feature maps and the input raster data often differ -- for example, every feature in the feature map might "correspond" (informally) to a 4x4 patch of pixels in the input. Different feature maps of the CNN also often have different resolutions.

In general, "multi-scale architecture" is a vague term used to express the idea that a neural network somehow integrates information from both the small scale (high resolution feature maps) and the large scale (lower resolution feature maps). Exactly what "integrates information" means varies a lot in different contexts.

In the context of this paper, "multi-scale architecture" means that the latent space of the generative model is split up across multiple feature maps of different resolutions, and the model has to integrate "information" across these different scales to perform inference/sampling.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer for your wonderful effort to write things down for me. I have few question from your answer itself,
1. the 4x4 map is basically coming the kernel size of sth like that? (If I understand it correctly).
2.what is raster data? You simply mean input data right?
3. high res feature map means looking into lots of pixels? Just want to understand scale and resolution via some example.

Comment: 1. either pooling or striding in the network, yes 2. raster just means data arranged in a regular grid -- for example, pixels in an image. image data is an example of raster data., 3. for example, if your original image was 256 x 256 pixels, you might have a high resolution (small scale) feature map of 256 x 256 features, and a low resolution (large scale) map of 32 x 32 features.

Comment: .: 3. I see. 32x32 portion of an image. Right?

Comment: If your feature map is 32x32 and your input was 256x256, then informally, each feature corresponds to an 8x8 region of pixels

Comment: Thanks. Thanks for the big help. Got it.